# Shining LEDs make noise while image processing

Tags: c#, image-processing, filter, aforge, led

I'm using Aforge Framework. trying to seperate three kind of LEDs (red,green,yellow close to each other every Led). When i looked them i se everything is good. Red is Red, Green is green, yellow is yellow. But when i looked them with Cam, i see only shining White. I have tried many kind of filter (ofcourse HSL, Gamma, Brightness, Contrast, Grayscale etc.) and mix of them. But none of them gave me the results thet i have expected. %5 of Red i can only see in 30x30 piksel of box when red LED is active. is there any other way to make LEDS color significant?

Comment: Get an IR blocking filter for the camera. The LEDs are likely putting out more infrared light than visible light.

Comment: any kind of IR filter will solve my problem or depends on filter type?

Comment: With a little research I'm sure you could figure it out. My comment was based solely on knowledge that cameras can pick up IR light by default, and that LEDs get freakishly warm. Another option might be to  point the camera at a piece of paper with the LEDs shining on it. You might pick up less of the IR from that.

Comment: Oh hey... Try a piece of clear glass over the LED.

Comment: yes i tried it but paper emiting color too much. My Leds are close to each others. By the way thanks for your advice. I think i will try IR filter to solve.

Comment: @Logarr Any change with glass or without glass. I have tried many things to get color clearly.

Comment: LEDs might be bright enough to saturate the camera so you should underexpose until it's clear that's not the problem. The sensor uses a matrix of color filters so it might not have the resolution you require, try getting a close-up shot to magnify the image.

Comment: @Mark, infact one purpose of proccessing image of LEDs expose if any wrong resistor used while our production. it's not in my hands. Some LEDs shining realy powerfull and some are not. My duty is try to figure out what are their colors. I dont have any chance to change power of LEDs.

Comment: What I meant was to change the exposure of the camera, not the LEDs. If you can't get that then my only suggestion is to look at the edge of the light blob rather than its entirety.

Comment: @freewave "My duty is try to figure out what are their colors."  In that case, a camera is the wrong instrument: use a spectrometer.  There are a variety of mini-spectrometers that will tell you an LED's color quickly and easily and with a precision that no camera could ever hope to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

I've Solved My Problem with black colored Acetate paper. First I've tried 1.44" diskette to filter, After good results i've decided to make my own filter with Acetate paper using printer. Results are satisfying on every color.

Comment: Great. You can accept your own answer, it will help if others may face the same problem in the future.

Comment: This was exactly my suggestion, reducing the exposure. Glad you found a way to do it.